# MQ Message shows different in different client application

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

when we connect the MQ using MQ Explorer we are getting different message and when we connect from RFH Util we are getting different message.

From java we can see the message is coming as com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage.
MQ Explorer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnEVF.png)
RFH Util:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5QTK.png)

RFH Util is giving correct value. 
My question is, if we use our java code how we can get the correct value? currently we are getting the wrong value in java. 
Expected is "!" but in MQ Explorer and java we are getting is "|".

Messages are coming from : Mainframe -> MQ -> java

it can be an encryption problem,

```
if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage aTextMessage = (TextMessage) message;   
            System.out.println(aTextMessage.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to d[ata conversion](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005729&aid=1) rather than encryption.  Are both of your clients connecting from the same machine?   You should check how the data conversion is being done.  You may also wish to review the [MQ knowledge](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032100_.htm) center.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we are able to resolve the issue, from the screenshots we understood that java is expecting EBSIDIC character set, so we change the corrector set to EBSIDIC (“037”) from Mainframe and it resolve the issue.
Mainframe changes : FUNCTION DISPLAY-OF (WS-AREA, 037)
Earlier it was FUNCTION DISPLAY-OF (WS-AREA, 500)

Thanks.